# Is it normal that gradient text is visible through header menu?

Tags: html, css

I am making a webpage with header menu,
and content has gradient text somewhere.

I just found out that the text is visible through the header menu, it seems the text somehow makes the header menu transparent.

the text is visible through the menu

[image]

supposed to look like:

[image]

Is this normal? Is there any other way to make gradient text without affecting other elements?

css of the header and the text looks like this by the way:

```
#header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.content_right_text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 10%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a z-index to your header element so that it stays on top even while scrolling as the position is set to sticky.

```
#header {
    position: sticky;
    .
    .
    .
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! silly me, I tried to put z-index in the header already in developer console on Chrome but it somehow didn't work so I thought it wasn't the solution